# Is there any example which can show that the change of the order of integration is not plausible when the improper integral exists?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be continuous on $Q=\{(x,y)\mid x>0,y>0\}$ and $\iint_Q |f(x,y)|$ converge.
 $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y \stackrel{?}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x$$
Is there any example to show that the equality is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, because under the assumptions you gave, you are allowed to interchange the order of integration by Fubini-Tonelli's theorem and the equality will always be true.

If an integral exists absolutely, you are allowed to interchange the order of the integrals as you want. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem

Edit: It does not matter in this case whether the integrals are understood as Lebesgue-integrals or improper Riemann-integrals. As $\iint_Q |f(x,y)|$ converges, we know that Fubini holds and

$$\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{[0,\infty)}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y =\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{[0,\infty)}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}x$$

as Lebesgue-integrals. But if an integral exists in the sense of Lebesgue, then the corresponding improper Riemann integral exists too and they are equal. You can prove this for example by using dominated convergency and $|f(x,y)|$ as the dominating fuction:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y = \lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{0}^m \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^n f(x,y) dx dy = \lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{[0,m]} \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,n]} f(x,y) dx dy = \lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{[0,\infty)} \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,\infty)} f_{m,n}(x,y)dx dy = \int_{[0,\infty)} \int_{[0,\infty)} \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_{m,n}(x,y)dx dy = \int_{[0,\infty)} \int_{[0,\infty)} f(x,y)dxdy$$

where

$$f_{m,n}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
 f(x,y), \ \ x \leq n, y \leq m\\
 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ otherwise
\end{cases}. $$

The Lebesgue-integrals are the ones where the range is denoted as a set.

Comment: The integral is understood as a kind of Riemann improper integral over an unbounded set. How can I use the definition of improper integral to prove that Fubini’s Theorem holds for unbounded sets in Riemann improper integral's sense?  Here I apply the definition of improper integral in Courant's text for calculus and analysis.

Comment: Now I understand. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: As a freshman, I have litte understanding about Lebesgue integral. Can we prove it without exposing to Lebegue integral?

Comment: So you do not know about the Lebesgue convergence theorems (dominated convergence, monotone convergence)? Then do you have a version of Fubini's theorem for Riemann integrals which we can use?

Comment: When the region is bounded and the integrand is continuous on it, the Fubini theorem holds, We only prove this case.

Comment: Ok and how should we interpret the first integral over $Q$? Does it mean that the iterated integrals $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |f(x,y)| dx dy$ and $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |f(x,y)| dy dx$ exist and are equal? Or is this understood as a high-dimensional Riemann-integral? And if it's a high-dimensional Riemann-integral: Have you already proven that the high dimensional integral equals the iterated integrals then?

Comment: The first integral means for any compact set and Jordan-measurable sets increasing to Q, integral of l f l over it  exist and are all the same.

Comment: I cannot think of an easy way to prove that (or let's say a way without having to prove additional theorems) because at some point you will have to interchange a limit and an integral. There you would need a version of the "monotone convergency theorem" for riemann-integral. But I assume you have not already proved something like that have you?